# How far is the sphere spectrum to be tilting/silting

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

In the last years the following definition of a tilting/silting object in an arbitrary  triangulated category with coproducts emerged:
Let $\mathcal D$ be a triangulated category with coproducts and with suspension functor $X\mapsto X[1]$, and fix an object $S\in\mathcal D$. For $I\subseteq\mathbb Z$ we set $$S^{\perp_I}=\{X\in{\mathcal D}\mid {\mathcal D}(S,X[i])=0, \forall i\in I\}$$ and we say that $S$ is silting if $\left(S^{\perp_{>0}}, S^{\perp_{\leq0}}\right)$ is a t-structure. Further $S$ is called tilting if it is silting and ${\mathrm A\mathrm d\mathrm d}(T)\subseteq S^{\perp_{\neq0}}$, where ${\mathrm A\mathrm d\mathrm d}(S)$ is the additive closure of $S$. (see Definition 4.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02677, or Definition 2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04700, or Definition 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.05817.pdf etc.).

Now I would like to specialize $\mathcal D$ to be the homotopy category of spectra and $S$ to be the sphere spectrum. It is known that $S$ induces a t-structure (e.g. Theorem 1.49 in [https://math.univ-angers.fr/~powell/documents/2011/notes_Brixen2011.pdf](https://math.univ-angers.fr/%7Epowell/documents/2011/notes_Brixen2011.pdf)). Now my question is if the sphere spectrum is silting in the above sense. I guess it is not tilting but I'd like to have a simple explanation. I have to admit that my understanding of the homotopy category of spectra is very poor, and perhaps some, if not all answers to these questions are obvious. Actually my first aim with this question is to understand better what a silting/tilting object is or isn't. If someone could give me a reference for reading basic facts about homotopy category of spectra this is a welcomed bonus. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your definition of *silting*, isn't this true of the sphere spectrum basically by definition of the standard t-structure? As in, aren't $\mathbb{S}^{\perp_{\le0}}$ exactly the connective spectra?

Comment: I suppose it's the connected spectra, not the connective ones, since $\pi_0$ must also vanish for a spectrum to be in $S^{\perp \leq 0}$.  So $S$ is silting (as the original question already suggests). $S$ isn't tilting, though: to be tilting, $S$ would have to have homotopy groups concentrated in degree zero. (See Def. 4.1 in the paper by Psaroudakis and Vitoria linked in the original question.) Of course the failure of the homotopy groups of $S$ to be concentrated in degree zero is precisely due to the nontriviality of the higher stable homotopy groups of spheres.

Comment: Thank you #A.S., your comment clarifies a lot.

Comment: What's the $T$ in the definition of tilting?